The child process does not start with syscall(SYS_clone3, …) + CLONE_VM
Hello, everyone.
It is necessary that the calling process and the child process are in the same memory space.
Therefore, I use the CLONE_VM flag.
But the child process does not start.
It looks like something is wrong with the allocation of memory for the stack.
Could you please explain the reason?
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE          /* syscall() */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64     /* getrlimit() */

#include <sched.h>              /* CLONE_* constants */
#include <linux/sched.h>        /* struct clone_args */
#include <sys/syscall.h>        /* SYS_* constants */
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>             /* uintptr_t */
#include <err.h>                /* err() */

#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <signal.h>

void spawn(void)
{
    struct rlimit       rlim;
    struct clone_args   cl_args = {0};
    uint64_t            stack_size;
    void                *stackBot;
    void                *stackTop;
    pid_t               pid;

    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim) == -1)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "getrlimit");
    stack_size = rlim.rlim_cur;

    stackBot = mmap(NULL, stack_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_GROWSDOWN |
                    MAP_STACK, -1, 0);
    if (stackBot == MAP_FAILED)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "mmap");

    long count = stack_size / sizeof(uint64_t);
    stackTop = (uint64_t *)stackBot + count - 1;

    printf("stack_size:      %lu\n", stack_size);
    printf("stack_size/2:    %lu\n", stack_size / 2);
    printf("stack_size/4:    %lu\n", stack_size / 4);
    printf("stack_size/8:    %lu\n", stack_size / 8);
    printf("stack_size/16:   %lu\n", stack_size / 16);
    printf("stack_size/4096: %lu\n", stack_size / 4096);   /* PAGESIZE */

    printf("stackBotAddr: %p\n", (void *)stackBot);
    printf("stackTopAddr: %p\n", (void *)stackTop);

    printf("stackBotVal: %lu\n", *(uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)stackBot);
    printf("stackTopVal: %lu\n", *(uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)stackTop);

    printf("stackTopAddr-stackBotAddr: %lu\n", (void *)stackTop - stackBot);

    printf("stackBotCast: %lu\n", (uint64_t)(uintptr_t)stackBot);
    printf("stackTopCast: %lu\n", (uint64_t)(uintptr_t)stackTop);

    cl_args.flags       = CLONE_FILES | CLONE_IO | CLONE_VM;
    cl_args.exit_signal = SIGCHLD;
    cl_args.stack       = (uint64_t)(uintptr_t)stackBot;
    cl_args.stack_size  = (void *)stackTop - stackBot;

    pid = syscall(SYS_clone3, &cl_args, sizeof(cl_args));
    switch(pid) {
        case -1:
            munmap(stackBot, stack_size);
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "syscall");
        case 0:     /* Child */
            printf("Hello from child. Child's pid: %d\n", getpid());
            munmap(stackBot, stack_size);
            break;
        default:    /* Parent */
            printf("Hello from parent. Parent's pid: %d\n", getpid());
            break;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    spawn();

    printf("Before last while\n");
    while(1) {
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Debugging with gdb leads to
[Detaching after fork from child process 16095]

attach process-id via gdb leads to
Attaching to process 16095
warning: process 16095 is a zombie - the process has already terminated
ptrace: Operation not permitted.

Before using clone3(), I tried to solve the problem through the fork() and clone() functions.
I refused to fork() because the parent and child processes must have the same memory space.
The clone() function did not work because a file descriptor should have been passed to the child process, but if the CLONE_VM flag was present, the file descriptor changed spontaneously. I also found two useful links on this issue:

Linux: Using "clone3" and "waitid";
Stack head using the clone3 system call — sourcehut lists.

But the child process never starts.

What happens if you change while(1) to getchar() or sleep(100)?

Not sure about the problem in your code, but from lists.sr.ht/~skeeto/public-inbox/%3CNi9xBAu--3-9%40tutanota.com%3E I have constructed a working clone3() example with CLONE_VM turned on: https://pastebin.com/pZhHSvZ6

Hello, @stark. Thanks for the comment. Adding getchar() or sleep(100) doesn't change anything.

Hello @MaximilianGerhardt. Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to make a solution. Without CLONE_VM and stack definition this syscall works. I guess it's something with defining stack boundaries or alignment. Also the pointer to the lowest byte of stack has the type u64 according to man clone. That's probably how it should be. Also when casting cl_args.stack = (__aligned_u64)(uintptr_t)stackBot; ccls (I use ccls) repots: 'aligned' attribute ignored when parsing type. struct clone_args uses __aligned_uint64_t.

Experimentally, it was found out that when creating threads, when the calling process and the child process are in the same address space (the CLONE_VM flag), the clone and clone3 system calls cannot be called from a high-level language (C) using the  wrapper function syscall(2). In this case, syscall(2) starts the child process without a stack frame and a return address, so it will not be able to return. The description on the man pages for clone(2), which suggests creating a thread (the CLONE_VM flag) using, for example,
long syscall(SYS_clone3, struct clone_args *cl_args, size_t size);

is a documentation error. The solution to this problem is described in detail in the article Practical libc-free threading on Linux. I am also very grateful to the author of this article for individual comments.
